# constant setting in Laravel 4 Packages (config.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, package

I am developing an application with Laravel 4, I am developing package for admin panel for it, now I need to have some some kind of settings to be shared in the whole package, in this case need an array that holds the whole models' names.
Question:
Where is the best location to store this setting? and if it is in the config.php file how do I have to use the variables stored in that in application, because it's simply a PhP file which returns an array and I have no idea how to access this file and retrieve its data

Answer (score 1):

You can put your configuration in a php file inside the app/config or package src/config directory.
For example, you can have a myconfig.php with the following contents:

```
<?php

return array(
        'config_name'        => array('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
);

?>
```

You can get the value of 'config_name' with the following code:

```
Config::get('myconfig.config_name')
```

Comment: your answer was helpful but for this will get the value of myconfig.php file inside the main application not in the admin panel package can you modify it to get the value inside myconfig.php inside the config folder of package

Comment: Checkout the Laravel documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages There is a 'config' directory inside the package where you can put your package configuration.